# Overheard/to be heard

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, synonyms

I need to say that a person spoke to another in a way with the intention people near by could also hear it.

Can I put it as follows?

> John spoke to Jane to be heard by his family.

Comment: John spoke loud enough to be heard by his family.

Comment: BTW, you might use a verb such as *mutter*, "grunted" or "grumble", if the intentions is to vice a complaint.

Comment: John spoke to Jane so as to be overheard by his family.

Comment: The intention is to inform the family and not to Jane. He is simply pretending to talk to her.